# sending bmp usng sockets

Tags: android, sockets, bmp

I'm trying to send bmp image using socket. I have such code on android:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MainActivity.bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20,
                    stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
OutputStream os = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
os.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
os.flush();
```

and on PC:

```
String q = SockIn.readLine();
File file = new File("filename.bmp");

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(q);
```

in bmp file I only get up to 401 bytes, which of course is corrupt bmp image. what am I doing wrong?

**MODIFIED**
modified PC side, now the code is:

```
InputStream in_ = clientSocket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out_ = new FileOutputStream("filename.bmp");
final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = -1;
int i = 0;
while ((read = in_.read(buffer)) != -1) {
out_.write(buffer, 0, read); 
System.out.println(i);
i++;

}

in_.close();
out_.close();


System.out.println("Done");
```

It never gets to last line( println("Done") ). when I close android program, it gets to last line and bmp opens succesfully

Comment: Here is a link to the answer to the edited question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885159/android-sending-bmp-using-sockets/

Just a heads up, you should not be asking the same question in two different threads on SO. It will likely get your questions closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reading logic is completely off. You only use a `readLine()` once and then write that to file. The data that was written to the socket on the device side was binary. That means that trying to read it as if it were textual (as `readLine()` does) will return meaningless junk. The reason it's usually 401 bytes long is that `readLine()` will look for the first newline character combination and return everything up to that as a `String`. This is not what you want.

What you need is a loop that will read from the socket and write into the file as long as there is data in the socket. A standard copy loop should suffice here.

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(...);
final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int read = -1;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);

in.close();
out.close();
```

Note that the above code isn't tested but something to that effect should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reading a String if you are sending a byte ?

Try those setp one by one only if the previous did not worked.

> **1. Read() and don't Readline() what you are writing**
>
> If you write a byte, read a byte

```
Byte obj = SockIn.read();
```

> **2. Encode your array before sending**

```
Base64.encodeBase64String(byteArray);
```