# android sending bmp using sockets

Tags: android, sockets, bmp

I'm trying to send bmp image using socket. I have such code on android:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MainActivity.bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20,
                stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
OutputStream os = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
os.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
os.flush();
```

and on PC:

```
InputStream in_ = clientSocket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out_ = new FileOutputStream("filename.bmp");
final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = -1;
int i = 0;
while ((read = in_.read(buffer)) != -1) {
out_.write(buffer, 0, read); 
System.out.println(i);
i++;

}

in_.close();
out_.close();


System.out.println("Done");
```

It never gets to last line( println("Done") ). It only does when I close android program, it gets to last line and bmp opens succesfully. problem is in_.read waits after android has finished transmitting, and i can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close the socket/OutputStream on the device side so the PC side doesn't know that there is no more data and so it just spins in the while loop reading 0 bytes at a time.

Also, if you're going to use my solution, please mark me as the accepted answer in your  [previous thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884396/sending-bmp-usng-sockets/16884678#16884678)

Comment: and so how should I make it work? how other software send data using sockets?

Comment: If all you're sending from Android is the bitmap then simply say os.close() after you're done. If you will be sending more data after the bitmap than precede the bitmap data with a length marker. That way you will know how many bytes to read on the PC side.